# Interpreting tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

Good day all,

Some months ago I initiated a PPC Google Adwords campaign with a company that specialises in it.  They provided me with tracking code to track conversions on my website for visitors that came on my website through the adverts they put up. However, I have a sneaking suspicion that this tracking in reality is not specific to visitors who come through their adverts and in reality tracks all conversions from all visitors and gives the credit to them.

They've already been giving me reports of click-throughs that seem wildly exaggerated when compared to what Google Analytics is telling me.

Here's a link to the tracking code they provided:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6f3I3dViQeIZ1lfclFESzJEOFF1MENlSEZGTUFzMGduQkpr

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related.

Comment: I think the tags I used do make it relevant.